# How can we prevent multiple variants of the same question?

Tags: discussion, questions

Is there anything we can do to prevent the multiple "how can we keep Trump out of the White House" variants?  Can we post a reminder to search prior questions before posting?

Comment: Never seen so much hope in faithless electors.

Comment: As someone who clearly isn't on Hillary's side, I must say I don't really see any harm in multiple "how can we keep Trump out of the White House"  questions, assuming said questions are not rude, objective, and actually ask interesting (and at the core, distinct) questions about political process. Just because the impetus for a question is opposition to Trump, it doesn't make it a bad question - OR, not useful to someone who supports Trump, for future elections, for that matter.

Comment: It's just getting redundant.

Comment: Vote to close then. It only takes four others or a moderator to agree with you that the question is indeed a duplicate for it to be closed.

Comment: Redundant as in "this was already answered"? See my answer below - VTC as duplicate. Redundant as in "I am sick of hearing about faithless electors"? Wait for a couple of months, till the idea exits the zeitgeist/meme pool

Comment: A little bit of both.

Answer (score 6):

"Can we do anything" - ***Yes***.

- If the question is asking the same thing that was already answered in another question, close it as a duplicate (if you don't have required reputation to VTC, comment and flag for closing)

  - For extra credit, expand the duplicate target with a new answer or an edit to existing good answer, to turn it into what SE considers "canonical post".
- If the question is unanswerable (any answer is subjective opinion, or just a rant), close it with appropriate close reason (same caveat re: not enough rep).
- If a question is trivial and can be answered with simple Google search, or Wiki lookup, or otherwise bad, downvote it (and copy Google query into a comment explaining why you downvoted, for extra credit).
- If the question has a good idea, but a ranty/ConspTheory component, you can salvage it by editing out the crud and leave the good question inside. Alternately, simply post a better more objective version of a question if it's too unsalvageable, though this approach has ethical implications depending on how much of an idea you borrow.
- If you simply are tired of seeing the questions on a specific topic, assuming they are tagged properly, you can ignore specific tags on a site. Or, y'know, just not pay attention. And do what Londoners are advised to do if they don't like the weather.

Comment: This seems to be a general recommendation; I think, the OP has asked, whether we can do something *besides* the standard SE practice?

Comment: @bytebuster - standard SE practice seems more than sufficient unless explicitly proven otherwise. The question which specifically triggered the OP asking was Dupe-VTCed, as a matter of fact, very quickly.